# Long SQL query with hibernate compared to JDBC (h2 database)

Tags: java, sql, performance, hibernate

I have already posted a related question but I'm re asking the question here with more details:

I execute an SQL query from my application with hibernate and the following code:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("sql.namedquery.captureinfo");
Long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Object[]> sqlList = query.list();
Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.err.println("SQL query took" + (t1 - t0));
```

The time to process this query is around 6s. I use H2 as the underlying database.
The named query is defined as follows:

```
<sql-query name="sql.namedquery.captureinfo">
<return-scalar column="eoid"                        type="int"/>
<return-scalar column="oid"                         type="int"/>
<return-scalar column="capture.obs_sys_id"          type="int"/>
<return-scalar column="capture.obs_mys_id"          type="int"/>
<return-scalar column="mid"                         type="int"/>
<return-scalar column="hdwr.type_hdwr"              type="string"/>
<return-scalar column="element_capture.description" type="string"/>
<return-scalar column="element_capture.dataf"       type="string"/>
<return-scalar column="geometrie.point"             type="materialized_blob"/>
<return-scalar column="geometrie.polygon"           type="materialized_blob"/>
<return-scalar column="element_capture.date_min"    type="date"/>
<return-scalar column="gid"                         type="int"/>
<return-scalar column="hdwr.nom"                    type="string"/>
select eo.id as eoid,o.id as oid,o.obs_sys_id,o.obs_mys_id,m.id as mid,m.type_hdwr,eo.description,eo.dataf,g.point,g.polygon,eo.date_min,g.id as gid,m.nom from element_capture eo left outer join geometrie g on eo.eo_geometrie_id = g.id left outer join hdwr m on eo.eo_hdwr_id = m.id left outer join capture o on eo.eo_capture_id = o.id
</sql-query>
```

Using the embedded SQL client for H2 to perform the exact same query, it is executed in less than a second.
I also tested using JDBC directly to check if the overhead was caused by the JDBC driver. Here is the code:

```
package test;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:data/mydatabase", "XXX", "YYY");
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String request =
            "select eo.id as eoid,o.id as oid,o.obs_sys_id,o.obs_mys_id,m.id as mid,m.type_hdwr,eo.description,eo.dataf,g.point,g.polygon,eo.date_min,g.id as gid,m.nom from element_capture eo left outer join geometrie g on eo.eo_geometrie_id = g.id left outer join hdwr m on eo.eo_hdwr_id = m.id left outer join capture o on eo.eo_capture_id = o.id";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(request);

        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery();
        while(res.next())
        {
            System.out.println(res.getInt(1) + "|" + res.getInt(2) + "|" + res.getInt(3) + "|" + res.getInt(4) + "|"
                + res.getInt(5) + "|" + res.getString(6) + "|" + res.getString(7) + "|" + res.getString(8) + "|"
                + res.getDate(11) + "|" + res.getInt(12) + "|" + res.getString(13));
            Blob a = res.getBlob(9);
            Blob b = res.getBlob(10);
            a.getBytes(0, (int)a.length()); // make sure to stream out the blob
            //b.getBytes(0, (int)b.length());  // commented out as b is null in every record

        }
        Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((end - start) + "ms");
        res.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Executing this code takes also around a second (including printing out the results in the console, there are 6398 records retrieved from the database).

So there is quite an overhead between the hibernate and JDBC version for the same query, which I dont understand. I would expect a slight overhead, but not that much.
I enabled verbose logging of hibernate, here is the beginning of the log:

```
11:42:49,083 TRACE QueryPlanCache:200 - Located native-sql query plan in cache (select eo.id as eoid,o.id as oid,o.obs_sys_id,o.obs_mys_id,m.id as mid,m.type_hdwr,eo.description,eo.dataf,g.point,g.polygon,eo.date_min,g.id as gid,m.nom from element_capture eo left outer join geometrie g on eo.eo_geometrie_id = g.id left outer join hdwr m on eo.eo_hdwr_id = m.id left outer join capture o on eo.eo_capture_id = o.id)
11:42:49,112 TRACE ConnectionProxyHandler:110 - Handling invocation of connection method [prepareStatement]
11:42:49,113 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:295 - Obtaining JDBC connection
11:42:49,115 TRACE DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:171 - Total checked-out connections: 1
11:42:49,116 DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:192 - Opening new JDBC connection
11:42:49,121 DEBUG DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:202 - Created connection to: jdbc:h2:data/mydatabase, Isolation Level: 2
11:42:49,122 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:301 - Obtained JDBC connection
11:42:49,142 DEBUG SQL:104 - select eo.id as eoid,o.id as oid,o.obs_sys_id,o.obs_mys_id,m.id as mid,m.type_hdwr,eo.description,eo.dataf,g.point,g.polygon,eo.date_min,g.id as gid,m.nom from element_capture eo left outer join geometrie g on eo.eo_geometrie_id = g.id left outer join hdwr m on eo.eo_hdwr_id = m.id left outer join capture o on eo.eo_capture_id = o.id
11:42:49,144 TRACE JdbcResourceRegistryImpl:65 - Registering statement [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyHandler@bf831db[valid=true]]
11:42:49,146 TRACE JdbcResourceRegistryImpl:75 - Registering last query statement [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyHandler@bf831db[valid=true]]
11:42:49,146 TRACE AbstractStatementProxyHandler:88 - Handling invocation of statement method [getWrappedObject]
11:42:49,147 TRACE JdbcResourceRegistryImpl:75 - Registering last query statement [prep3: select eo.id as eoid,o.id as oid,o.obs_sys_id,o.obs_mys_id,m.id as mid,m.type_hdwr,eo.description,eo.dataf,g.point,g.polygon,eo.date_min,g.id as gid,m.nom from element_capture eo left outer join geometrie g on eo.eo_geometrie_id = g.id left outer join hdwr m on eo.eo_hdwr_id = m.id left outer join capture o on eo.eo_capture_id = o.id]
11:42:49,148 TRACE Loader:1798 - Bound [1] parameters total
11:42:49,148 TRACE AbstractStatementProxyHandler:88 - Handling invocation of statement method [executeQuery]
11:42:53,537 TRACE JdbcResourceRegistryImpl:118 - Registering result set [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ResultSetProxyHandler@42ea7f9f[valid=true]]
11:42:53,538 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getStatement]
11:42:53,540 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getStatement]
11:42:53,540 TRACE Loader:870 - Processing result set
11:42:53,541 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [next]
11:42:53,542 DEBUG Loader:873 - Result set row: 0
11:42:53,544 DEBUG Loader:1377 - Result row: 
11:42:53,545 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,549 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,550 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-6398] as column [eoid]
11:42:53,551 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,552 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,553 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-6398] as column [oid]
11:42:53,554 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,555 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,556 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-14] as column [capture.obs_sys_id]
11:42:53,557 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,558 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,558 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [13] as column [capture.obs_mys_id]
11:42:53,559 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,560 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,560 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [1] as column [mid]
11:42:53,561 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,562 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,562 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [APN] as column [hdwr.type_hdwr]
11:42:53,563 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,564 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,564 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [obsstatus=NON_VU;meta.filename=tap_1387464655536.zip] as column [element_capture.description]
11:42:53,565 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,565 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,566 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [tap_1387464655536.jpg] as column [element_capture.dataf]
11:42:53,567 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getBlob]
11:42:53,590 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,591 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [[B@2dce2a8d] as column [geometrie.point]
11:42:53,592 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getBlob]
11:42:53,593 TRACE BasicExtractor:67 - Found [null] as column [geometrie.polygon]
11:42:53,596 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getDate]
11:42:53,598 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,599 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [2013-12-19] as column [element_capture.date_min]
11:42:53,600 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,602 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,603 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-6412] as column [gid]
11:42:53,604 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,605 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,606 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [TQ9GY] as column [hdwr.nom]
11:42:53,608 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [next]
11:42:53,609 DEBUG Loader:873 - Result set row: 1
11:42:53,610 DEBUG Loader:1377 - Result row: 
11:42:53,611 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,612 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,613 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-6397] as column [eoid]
11:42:53,614 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,619 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,620 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-6397] as column [oid]
11:42:53,621 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,623 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,624 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-14] as column [capture.obs_sys_id]
11:42:53,625 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,626 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,627 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [13] as column [capture.obs_mys_id]
11:42:53,628 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,629 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,630 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [1] as column [mid]
11:42:53,631 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,632 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,633 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [APN] as column [hdwr.type_hdwr]
11:42:53,634 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,634 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,635 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [obsstatus=A_REVOIR;meta.filename=tap_1387464653290.zip] as column [element_capture.description]
11:42:53,636 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,636 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,637 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [tap_1387464653290.jpg] as column [element_capture.dataf]
11:42:53,637 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getBlob]
11:42:53,639 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,639 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [[B@3f46a7e8] as column [geometrie.point]
11:42:53,640 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getBlob]
11:42:53,641 TRACE BasicExtractor:67 - Found [null] as column [geometrie.polygon]
11:42:53,642 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getDate]
11:42:53,644 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,645 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [2013-12-19] as column [element_capture.date_min]
11:42:53,646 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getInt]
11:42:53,647 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,647 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [-6411] as column [gid]
11:42:53,648 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [getString]
11:42:53,649 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [wasNull]
11:42:53,650 TRACE BasicExtractor:72 - Found [TQ9GY] as column [hdwr.nom]
11:42:53,650 TRACE AbstractResultSetProxyHandler:72 - Handling invocation of ResultSet method [next]
so on until  DEBUG Loader:873 - Result set row: 6397
```

As you can see the SQL query return scalar values, not entities so there is no overhead due to entity management.
So does all those operations performed by hibernate when parsing the results explain this extreme overhead ? I thought that specifying the return type in the named query for all my parameters would simplify hibernate jobs by not letting it guess the result types. What more can I do to speed things up with hibernate?

Comment: One obvious overhead is the outcome of retrieving a List of objects. So every result is both wrapped into a result set as well as stored into a list. Because the results are wrapped there also must be invocations on setters or non - default constructors and castings from the oject hibernate uses for storing the result. Though this doesn't explain this difference in performance.

Comment: An additional overhead may come from the Query - Object itself. When this Query is part of the HQL, there would be an additional parsing of it because the HQL is an abstraction of SQL to avoid vendor specific details and implementations of SQL.

Comment: Because that implies Scanners, building up a Syntax - Tree and compiling that Tree to the SQL - Statement that is executed against the database via the JDBC.

Comment: Thx for your comments. I stepped through the result processor with the debugger and found out the several steps/wrapper that the result goes around, as the log showed. I ended up setting a PassThroughResultTransformer to the query explicitely and this managed to get similar just a slight overhead wrt JDBC perf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that specifically defining the result type for the scalar was not enough and the overhead generated by hibernate to parse the result set was still large. I specifically set a PassThroughResultTransformer to my query, which effectively sped up parsing to just a slight overhead compared to JDBC query. The change in the first code extract from my question below is the following:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("sql.namedquery.captureinfo");
query.setResultTransformer(PassThroughResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
Long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Object[]> sqlList = query.list();
Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.err.println("SQL query took" + (t1 - t0));
```